# indent/pretty-printing utility for System Verilog

Tags: verilog, pretty-print, system-verilog

Not properly a programming question, but is anybody aware of a open source indent (similar to gnu indent or astyle) capable of indenting System Verilog?

More sophisticated pretty-printing (such as aligning assignments or reformatting source to fit 80 character lines) would be very nice to have, but basic indentation would already be useful.

Comment: This isn't the sort of question StackOverflow handles: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I don't see anything there that would make my question off-topic. Specifically 'software tools commonly used by programmers' is explicitly listed as a valid topic. Can you point me to the precise portion that leads you to your conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

### verilog-mode for Emacs

You can read all about it [here](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode).  Despite the name, it supports SystemVerilog as well.

### Vim syntax files

There are a few Vim syntax files floating around which will add syntax highlighting, as well as indentation to Vim.  Search for 'systemverilog vim'.

---

Both of the above will indent as you edit; if you are specifically looking for a tool to reformat an entire file, take a look at:

- http://www.veripool.org/projects/verilog-mode/wiki/Faq#How-do-I-reindent-Verilog-code-from-the-command-line